# What is the formal definition of Coupling efficiency

Tags: optics, photons, quantum-optics, fiber-optics, photonics

Does anyone knows the formal definition of Coupling efficiency?
I have been reading the term in photonics devices and optics.

I have been searching for it, but I could not find any.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, an efficiency is going to be the ratio of power or energy successfully delivered or used to the power input to the system

$$\eta =\frac{P_{out}}{P_{in}}$$

In the case of coupling efficiency, $P_{out}$ is the power coupled into the desired output mode or modes, or to a photdector or some other device, and $P_{in}$ is the power provided at the input of the coupling mechanism.